# Is there a way to import local configuration for Tomcat?

Tags: intellij-idea, tomcat

I see that in Intellij there is this option of *Edit Configuration -> + -> Select Tomcat Server -> Local*, then filling in with all the details.
There is also an option to store the configuration (the intellij option is called *Store as project file*) in your file system and use it later.
[image]

I am wondering if there is sth I miss, because if I try to import the XML configuration later and not create the Tomcat local setup from scratch again, I cannot find the option to import it.
Can you tell me how to import this .xml file that is saved from *Store as project file*?

Comment: Do you get any error when importing configuration?

Comment: No, what I actually don't find is the actual Intellij option that allows me to import a tomcat config file.

Comment: I found the issue, the problem was that I did not have the project imported ok. If the project is imported. correctly and the run configuration files are places in the .ides folder used by intellij, then intellij autodetects the configuration and creates a run configuration.